# Why does Windows Media Player show Windows system sounds?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I don't know what exactly I did in Windows Media Player, but when I opened it up recently, it had countless amounts of system sounds such as "Battery Critical", "Log On", "Chimes", and every other Windows system sound. I tried deleting the files from WMP, but it said I don't have the permission from TrustedInstaller.

How do I get rid of these sounds in WMP?

Comment: As far as I know, WMP only lists the files that you have in your Music library. So open that library (Start menu -> Music), then right-click in an empty area and select Properties. Under "Library locations", make sure that it doesn't include any system directories. If it does, select it and click Remove.

Comment: user182945 You've probably set wmp to find all media on your pc to get this to happen.  If that's the case, do as Indrek says.  @Indrek you should make that an answer

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media Player only lists the files that you have in your Music library, so it looks like you have somehow set WMP to include all media files on your computer.

To fix this, you'll have to edit your Music library to only include the folder(s) where you keep your music:

- From Windows Media Player, go to Organize → Manage libraries → Music

  [image]
- Alternatively, open your Music library (Start menu → Music) and click on the link at the top, after "Includes:"

  [image]
- In the window that opens, go through the list and make sure it doesn't include any system folders. If it does, remove them.

  [image]